# Facebook Development Graph API Retrieve posts from user with token app_id|app_secret

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve posts and time from Facebook using their graph api for a website from a particular user, but using an access code which is the "app_id"|"app_secret" it returns posts but also puts the created date of comments in the array with blank messages.

I'm looking to get a specific number of posts, but the blank messages are counted. I don't want to make a second request.

If I test it on the Graph API explorer using a generated access token,it returns the messages only, no comments. Can I achieve this with my token.

I generate the token using

```
FBClient.Get("oauth/access_token", new { client_id = credentials.ApplicationId, client_secret = "secret", grant_type = "client_credentials" });
```

The difference with the graph API explorer token is that it is a “User Access Token” but I'm using an “App Access Token” but are using the exact same graph API URL and getting different results.

The access string I use is

```
posts.limit(20){message};
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the Facebook docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed
to filter the edge "feed" you use /{user-id}/posts which should according to FB docs "shows only the posts that were published by this person"

if you use a User Token this works as expected. Using an Application Access Token the same request brings back empty fields which look like the might be other fields like "comments, status etc..."